# How can I vectorize checking values in each row of DataFrame for a "kind" and updating a count?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, optimization, vectorization

I have constructed some large dataframes that correspond to contacts in a network graph. The format of these DataFrames are rows, where the index value is a unique identifier for a node in the graph, and column 1 is an integer that corresponds to a "type" of node (you could think of this as something like a color, all of type 1 are red, for instance):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv( 
    "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ethanagbaker/98062ebc83b3dd2018a1837d3e3b12df/raw/a59cb7645f6ca935e01a8dea04377da28847c365/testData.csv", 
    skiprows=1, header=None, index_col=0 
)
```

Columns 3-24 are the IDs of nodes that share an edge with the node specified by the row index, with a 0 indicating no neighbor. So, if columns 3 and 4 in row 1 have non-zero values, node 1 has an edge to those specified nodes. Columns 25-32 are intended to specify the number of neighboring nodes of each type for the node specified by the index, and are initialized as zeros. Here's an example of what this data looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmiP7.jpg . Node 1 is of type 6, with 6 neighbors: 373, 389, 175, 99, 127, and 167.

I have functional code that iterates over the rows, checks the columns that specify neighboring nodes, then looks up their type in the dataframe, and increments the count column. This works with the desired effect, but is slow. For clarity, the count for type `n` is in col `n + 24`. The runtime is about 4 minutes on a frame of 500 rows, but I need to scale this to ~50,000,000 rows. I've been trying to modify this to use `.apply()` or a vectorized approach, but can't quite see how to do it. Here's the fully functional iterative approach:

```py
def countNeighbors(contactMap):
    for index, row in contactMap.iterrows():
        for col in range(3,25):
            cellID = row[col]
            if cellID == 0:
                break
            else:
                cellType = contactMap[1][cellID]
                contactMap[24+cellType][index] += 1
    return contactMap

#run the function
contactMapCounted = countNeighbors(contactMap)
```

`contactMap` is the matrix described above, and I've exported a [sample one here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ethanagbaker/98062ebc83b3dd2018a1837d3e3b12df/raw/a59cb7645f6ca935e01a8dea04377da28847c365/testData.csv). Note that the index and header are *included and important*. Loading this as a pandas `DataFrame` should allow you to replicate this.

I assume I've just been staring at this for to long to see what to do here, but is there an obvious way to speed this up?

**Probably relevant edit**: Upon deeper testing, it seems that this function alone is quite fast, but I am using it in the following way, which is where I notice a substantial slowdown:

```py
n_shuffles = 100
while s < n_shuffles:
        #print(s)
        contactMap_Shuffled = contactMap.sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True)
        contactMap_Shuffled.index += 1
        contactMap_Shuffled.loc[:,25:] = 0  #Reset the count cols
        contactMap_Shuffled = countNeighbors(contactMap_Shuffled)
        s += 1
```

This is intended to randomize the index of the frame, then recalculate the count values as described. This is where I first noticed the slow down, and I had assumed the issue was with `countNeighbors()`, but perhaps it's something here...

Comment: You have some good detail here, but could you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that others can work off of?

Comment: @BradSolomon [Here is a sample contact matrix](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ethanagbaker/98062ebc83b3dd2018a1837d3e3b12df/raw/a59cb7645f6ca935e01a8dea04377da28847c365/testData.csv). You should be able to import it right to Pandas, node that the header and index are included here. I'll update the original post as well.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find an efficient way to vectorize `countNeighbors()`, but could roughly halve the execution time by avoiding the *chained indexing* (see [Returning a view versus a copy](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy)), i. e. by changing

```
                cellType = contactMap[1][cellID]
                contactMap[24+cellType][index] += 1
```

to

```
                cellType = contactMap.at[cellID, 1]
                contactMap.at[index, 24+cellType] += 1
```